# Making git daemon serve the repo I created

Tags: git, daemon

I've been wracking my brain over this and came to a possible conclusion with no solution. First, my dilemma.

I have a project where I can create a repo programmatically. I can edit the description of the repo, set the default branch, &c. This is fine.

I am also using `git daemon` to serve the folder where all the generated repos are kept. Here's where the issue steps in.

**I am able to clone the repo but the cloned repo's `.git` contents don't match the original repo.**

The only thing I can think of is that when I am *creating* these repos I am using my system's git process but when cloning I am using the `git daemon`'s process...I'm not even sure that makes sense and my hours of searching have turned up nothing.

For reference, here's the command I run to activate `git daemon`:

```sh
git daemon --reuseaddr --port=9999 --base-path=/Users/me/repos/ --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack --informative-errors --detach
```

Here's an example of a clone command:

```sh
git clone git://localhost:9999/me/test18.git
```

And here are the commands I run to create the repos:

```sh
git init
git remote add origin git://localhost:9999/me/repo.git
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/magic
# more stuff
```

These things work, I just need `git daemon` to serve my repos the way they are.

---

Here's an example of the contents of `.git/config` in the repo I create:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://localhost:9999/me/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "coolerbranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/coolerbranch
```

Here is that same repo cloned:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://localhost:9999/me/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

As you can see, the `[branch ...]` section doesn't match.

---

*Conversely, if there's another `git daemon` out there that I haven't found I'd love to hear about it. Github had been working on their own several years ago but abandoned it.*

*Also, I originally posted this question on SO but after further searching on other SE sites, I realized SF has more `git-daemon`-esque questions.*

---

[@Zoredache](https://serverfault.com/questions/1000976/making-git-daemon-serve-the-repo-i-created#comment1301498_1000976):

> Cloning a repo doesn't copy the configuration. Configuration is mostly local to the computer, user, or directory.

Without this knowledge, I was assuming there'd be a way to get git to sync the initial config upon cloning. Git's defaults are not overrideable by a server, only by the user.

Maybe git will allow this option someday, most likely not. Ah well.

Comment: I guess another way to ask is, how do I run commands against git-daemon over the built-in/system git?

Comment: I think git-daemon usage is pretty uncommon, and most people just use SSH for read-write, and  just the http backend for read-only.

Comment: I feared this was the case but had hoped I simply overlooked an article written on a random blog 12 years ago with a useful nugget of info that still worked. Alas, not this time.

Comment: BTW,  you may need to be more specific on what you mean by `the cloned repo's .git contents don't match the original repo`.  What exactly is different?  Is it a completely different repo with no similar commits, or what?  I am not a git daemon expert, but I am not sure you have given enough information yet, that I could attempt to replicate or even recognize the problem you are trying to get help with.

Comment: You're right, I just added more context.

Comment: `As you can see, the [branch ...] section doesn't match.` cloning a repo doesn't copy the configuration.  Configuration is mostly local to the computer, user, or directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103863/discussion-between-netoperator-wibby-and-zoredache).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the cloned .git should match the servers .git contents. For setting up a server, I would recommend that you follow the directions in the book https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server.

Comment: I've been over that page several times. Thanks to my discussion with @Zoredache, I discovered that git doesn't sync configs. Seems like an oversight but I guess there's nothing I can do about that.